# Ajax request with GET works but not with POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I make an ajax request with POST method and the below route:

```
router.post('/shows', function(req, res){
        model.find({}, function(sent, recieved){
            res.contentType('json');
            res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) });
        });
    });
```

I get error 500,

When I use ajax request with GET method and the below route

```
router.get('/shows', function(req, res){
    model.find({}, function(sent, recieved){
        res.contentType('json');
        res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) });
    });
});
```

it works.

I make an ajax request with jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/shows",
           dataType:"json"
       })
          .done(function( done ) {
                        console.log(done)
          });
```

My console says:

```
express deprecated res.send(status, body): 
Use res.status(status).send(body) instead node_modules/kraken-js/middleware/500.js:27:17
```

Any ideas why my post route is not returning data properly?

Comment: Are you sure that "/shows" route exists?

Comment: does your Node.js console show an error? How do you make the post request?

Comment: Edited my question to include more info.

Comment: Well. Your console says it all

Comment: I disagree, I actually tried with res.status also... same thing

Comment: Are you using [`bodyParser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware? If so, can you provide your code where you're using it?

Comment: Have you tried it without using `JSON.stringify` in your return? What about just `res.send({ "some": "json" });`